# Iterating through Laravel 4 custom collection

Tags: php, laravel

I have created my own collection in Laravel 4.
Below is the code,

```
    $family = Collection::make([
        ['name' => 'Mom', 'age' => 30],
        ['name' => 'Dad', 'age' => 31]
    ]);

    foreach ($family as $member) {
        echo $member->name;
        echo "<br>";
    }
    return;
```

The problem is, i cannot call 'name' or 'age' while iterating the loop.
Is there something wrong with the collection?

Comment: `Can you print_r($family)`?

Comment: print_r resulting this:
    Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Mom [age] => 30 ) [1] => Array ( [name] => Dad [age] => 31 ) ) )

Comment: It should be `$member['name'];`

Comment: That works! But why I can't use $member->name just like Laravel eloquent result?

Comment: I will post my answer for that. Maybe you can accept that right? And also i will explain it to my answer.

Comment: Is it clear now to you? Maybe you can put a green check? Tnx.

Comment: See how it says `=> Array ( [name]` in your first comment above? That means you have to use array syntax to access the values (e.g., `$member['name']`), but you're trying to use object syntax (e.g., `$member->name`). These are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have array of array's so that you can access that using `$member['name']`

For example:

If you have array of arrays

```
 Array
 (
  [0] => Array
    (
        [name] => Mom
        [age] => 30
    )
  [1] => Array
    (
        [name] => Dad
        [age] => 31
    )
 )
```

You can access that using below:

```
 foreach($family as $key => $member)
{
    echo $member['name'];
}
```

If you have object of arrays you can access that using `$member->name`

Example of array of objects:

```
Array
 (
  [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => Mom
        [age] => 30
    )
  [1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [name] => Dad
        [age] => 31
    )
)
```

You can access that using below:

```
 foreach ($family as $key => $member) 
 {
    echo $member->name;
 }
```

**NOTE:** To test or to see the resulted values use `print_r($result)` OR `var_dump($result)`

Comment: thanks. i ended up converting array to object using this function: json_decode(json_encode($array), FALSE)

Comment: Free tip there, @hellilyntax -- you can cast an array to an object using `object($array)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pure php solution:

```
$family = [
    ['name' => 'Mom', 'age' => 30],
    ['name' => 'Dad', 'age' => 31]
];

foreach ($family as $k=>$v) {
    echo $v["name"];
    echo "<br>";
}
return;
```

(I don't know "Laravel 4" sorry, but this should work)